# Elasticsearch analyzer configuration

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running term statistics in elasticsearch and I get the result:

```
 "tevez's": {
               "doc_freq": 165,
               "ttf": 245,
               "term_freq": 1,
               "tokens": [
                  {
                     "position": 722,
                     "start_offset": 4077,
                     "end_offset": 4084
                  }
               ],
               "score": 9.041515
```

How can I tell elasticsearch to consider `tevez's` and `tevez`

to be the same?

I also get:

```
"benched": {
               "doc_freq": 130,
               "ttf": 140,
               "term_freq": 1,
               "tokens": [
                  {
                     "position": 757,
                     "start_offset": 4292,
                     "end_offset": 4299
                  }
               ],
               "score": 9.278306
```

How can I tell elasticsearch to consider `benched` and `bench` to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `possessive_english` to remove `'s`
- use `porter` or other stemmer to remove tenses and something else

For english, here's a full [list](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/choosing-a-stemmer.html) of stemmers.

Also, you need to create the settings like:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "possessive": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "possessive_english"
          },
          "porter": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "language": "english"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "custom_english": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "porter",
              "possessive"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally request `$endpoint/$index/_analyze?analyzer=persian_keyword_analyzer&‌​text=$text` to view the stem effect.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to ignore digits? or words containing digits such as w3m or 34m etc

Comment: @osager What do you mean by ignoring digits? want to convert `w3m` to `wm`, `34m` to `m`? or something else?

Comment: I mean ignore them completely and don't calculate their statistics. By default ES returns the frequency of "3m" in the document which i'm not interested. I'm only interested in English words(or french.. etc)

Comment: @osager I think mapping char filter/pattern replace char filter can all implement this. maybe keep types token filter is not very suitable.